# Porting Android APK (With GPS_Provider) on BlackBerry PlayBook 2.1

Tags: android, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-android

We are trying to port an Android APK to BlackBerry Playbook 2.1. To do so we, followed steps given at http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/gettingstarted.html.

We have developed a sample application that shows you GPSData (longitude and latitude) in a `TextView`. The application is working fine on Android devices. Then we converted it into a BAR file. We have also checked the compatibility list and found only one issue with the size of logo which is not major. However, the application crashes on BlackBerry.

We are using `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` and `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`. Both are available because following condition returns true on the BlackBerry device:

```
if (GetLocation.mGPSLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    //this line of code write log into a file
    Log.debug(this.getClass() + " :: Caller :: " + caller,"Found GPS Provider");
    GetLocation.mGPSLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 10,GetLocation.mGPSLocationListener);
}
```

It seems that the issue with following code:

```
private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

Please let us know your views.

Comment: What is the specific error you are receiving when it crashes?

Comment: Unfortunately we are not able to record it. It just shows dialog with message "the application has stopped unexpectedly" on blackberry.

Comment: On android (android phone attached to PC and eclipse is running) we can have logcat but once the app is running on BlackBerry w don't know how to get it...